# Add more space to existing canvas without redrawing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've created a canvas that I've drawn images and texts on. Is it possible to add more space (height in my case) to the current canvas without having to redraw everything? I would like to add text below the already drawn items but to do this I have to add more height to canvas.

Or can I do it the other way around - create a too large canvas to start with and then add all my texts and in the end crop the canvas (removing white unused space)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like recursive's idea using a container that you first size short and then expand to reveal the extra canvas space needed to draw text.

Another common way of resizing a canvas is to bounce the canvas contents off a temporary canvas.

```
// create a temp canvas (no need to add it to the DOM)
var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
tempCanvas.width=mainCanvas.width;
tempCanvas.height=mainCanvas.height;

// draw the main canvas to the temp canvas
tempCtx.drawImage(mainCanvas,0,0);

// resize the main canvas
mainCanvas.height+=30;

// restore the main canvas content by drawing the temp canvas
mainCtx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put your canvas inside a container with a fixed target height.  If you set its `overflow` to `hidden`, then you can control how much can be seen.

Changing the dimensions of a canvas clear it, so that won't work.

Comment: +1, Nice workaround to the problem of canvas auto-clearing itself on height changes.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I want to save the canvas as an image in the end so I guess "overflow:hidden" will not work in my case, but otherwise a good solution!